# Import Error : cannot import name 'linlag' from 'scipy'

Tags: scipy, anaconda

Uninstalled & reinstalled scipy package, though cannot seem to import linalg function.

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-133368b721e2> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import sklearn
----> 3 from scipy import linlag

ImportError: cannot import name 'linlag' from 'scipy' (C:\Users\lenov\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a minor syntax error. It should be "linalg".